# Interpreting qpid-bench output

Tags: java, benchmarking, messaging, amqp, qpid

I'm running the qpid-bench tool that comes with Apache qpid against a couple different machines to bench mark the performance. I haven't been able to find any documentation on the output/results from the qpid-bench program. Here are the results from a sample test:

```
$ qpid-bench
broker = localhost                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
port = 5672                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
count = 1000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
window = 100000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
sample = 100000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
size = 1024                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
mode = BOTH                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
timestamp = false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
message_id = false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
message_cache = false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
persistent = false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
jms_publish = false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
jms_consume = false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
help = false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IoReceiver - localhost/127.0.0.1:5672 2011-12-23 09:39:11,427 INFO ...                                    
IoReceiver - localhost/127.0.0.1:5672 2011-12-23 09:39:11,427 INFO ...                                                             
NP: Fri Dec 23 09:39:11 PST 2011                   --                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               --                   NC: Fri Dec 23 09:39:11 PST 2011                                                                                                                                                                                                           
NP: 100000 6246.49 6246.49                         --                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               --                   NC: 100000 6205.01 6205.01                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
NP: 200000 6775.07 7401.38                         --                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               --                   NC: 200000 6758.58 7420.60                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
NP: 300000 6795.94 6838.07                         --                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               --                   NC: 300000 6782.27 6830.13                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
NP: 400000 6618.02 6136.10                         --                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               --                   NC: 400000 6609.28 6139.49                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
NP: 500000 6673.07 6902.74                         --                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               --                   NC: 500000 6662.31 6883.26                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
NP: 600000 6723.89 6990.07                         --                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               --                   NC: 600000 6707.36 6942.03                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
NP: 700000 6780.32 7139.80                         --                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               --                   NC: 700000 6775.07 7211.89                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
NP: 800000 6679.08 6047.05                         --                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               --                   NC: 800000 6673.67 6040.84                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
NP: 900000 6547.26 5654.51                         --                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
               --                   NC: 900000 6538.56 5627.15                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Producer Completed
Consumer Completed
```

I'll guess NP is the number published and NC is the number consumed per window. The first number is the number count of messages sent/received. What do the second and third numbers mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the source for QpidBench.java: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/java/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/tools/QpidBench.java

Here are the options for the qpid-bench command:

```
$ qpid-bench --help
   qpid-bench <options>
  -b, --broker    (localhost)   the broker hostname
  -p, --port      (5672)        the broker port
  -c, --count     (1000000)     the number of messages to send/receive, 0 means no limit
  -w, --window    (100000)      the number of messages to send before blocking, 0 disables
  --sample        (100000)      print stats after this many messages, 0 disables
  -i, --interval  (100000)      sets both --window and --sample
  -s, --size      (1024)        the message size
  -m, --mode      (BOTH)        one of publish, consume, or both
  --timestamp     (false)       set timestamps on each message if true
  --mesage-id     (false)       set the message-id on each message if true
  --message-cache (false)       reuse the same message for each send if true
  --persistent    (false)       set the delivery-mode to persistent if true
  --jms-publish   (false)       use the jms client for publish
  --jms-consume   (false)       use the jms client for consume
  --jms           (false)       sets both --jms-publish and --jms-consume
  -h, --help                    prints this message
```

The first number cumulative as defined by "double cumulative = 1000 * (double) count / (double) (time - start);" in QPidBench.java. i.e. the total number published or consumed at each sample period.

The second number interval is defined by "double interval = 1000 * ((double) opts.sample / (double) (time - lastTime));" in QpidBench.java. i.e. the number published or consumed at each sample period.

count is the number of messages published/consumed and opts.sample is the sample size as defined in the options when qpid-bench is ran.